# Weird race-condition in java ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, threadpoolexecutor, executor

I`m trying to make an api-checking app that must send requests asynchronously using the pool of bots while termination date is not reached.

On startup creates a `final List<Bot>` is created and will be executed until the termination date. The idea is that at each iteration of the `while` cycle, we would iterate through the `List<Bot>` and try to launch them through the executor in wrapper `BotRunner`. **(if the bot is already launched by another thread, we will simply hang on the `mutex` monitor and wait for completion `Bot#run` from another thread. After that - execute `Bot#run` normally)**.

After execution i see 1-2% of duplicating requests from different bots *(server sends correct data i swear)*. Looks like simple race-condition, but i don't realize what is causes. Is it `Bot`? - i suppose not (use synchronized). Is it `final List<Bot>`? - is guess no (we don't change state of list)

**Bot entity:**

```java
public class Bot 
{
    private final BotStatistic statisic = new BotStatistic();
    private final Object mutex = new Object();
    private String responseData;    

    void run() 
    {
        synchronized(mutex) {
          // first http call -> responseData = "j43iFS135SFSF";
          // second http call(responseData) -> {"success": "true"}
          // save to statistic
          // responseData = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**BotRunner entity:**

```java
public class BotRunner implements Runnable 
{
    private final Bot bot;
    
    public BotRunner(Bot bot) 
    {
        this.bot = bot;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
       bot.run();
    }
}
```

**Trying to execute in this way:**

```java
//init executor
LocalDateTime termination = LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(5L);
while (LocalDateTime.now().isBefore(termination)) 
{
    for (Bot bot : bots) 
    {
        executor.execute(new BotRunner(bot));
    }
}
//shutdown & close executor
```

**WHAT NOT WORKS:**

1. `String -> final StringBuffer` not helps.
2. Use local method variable `String` not helps.

Could someone say what i did wrong?

Comment: `mutex.wait()` in `synchronized` block???

Comment: Your BotRunner class seems entirely redundant.  `Bot` already implements `Runnable`.

Comment: What is “replica”? What does it have to do with `Bot`? Is it even important to the Question here? Write your issue description as simply as possible.

Comment: "if the bot is already launched by another thread, we will simply hang on the mutex monitor and wait for completion Bot#run from another thread." So, one Bot can do multiple calls to same target, hence duplication. Or do I miss something?

Comment: You right, @forty-two. But on each Bot#run in proceed it own responseData, but after execution i see the 1-2% of duplication responseData. Do you know what in causes? (server sends corrent data!)

Comment: @IndependenceCR Sorry, but it is not clear what "duplication" means in terms of response data

Comment: Okay, @forty-two. In my case, 'duplication' means 2 equal responseData from first http call in different bots

Comment: So we need to know what responseData is supposed to be, who generates it, etc. Is it the server that generates it? Is it guaranteed to be unique for each request?

Comment: Yep, @forty-two. Server generate and send unique responseData (UUID string usually) on each first http call

Comment: "on each first http call". What does that mean? First per connection or first per client IP or something else?

Comment: Iteration has a 2 stages: first http call (get ResponseData), and second httpCall (use ResponseData as url param). @forty-two

Comment: @IndependenceCR you say “*after execution i see the 1-2% of duplication responseData*” but your code does not contain anything to detect the “after execution” state reliably nor to inspect the result of the operation in this state. As soon as one thread completes the operation (leaves the `synchronized` block), the next thread can start the next operation (enter the `synchronized` block). There is no in-between where you could check the result without races. Nor any other place where checking the result could work.

Comment: I gather statistic from each bot after pool terminated and closed. @Holger

Comment: So your problem is with the `BotStatistic` object but for some reason, all your attempts were changes to the unrelated `responseData` variable?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the cause of your problem (which you do not actually explain), but since you emphasized the importance of every bot running in its own thread I must point out that calling **`Executor#execute` does *not* necessarily run its task on a background thread**. Read the Javadoc; it clearly states that the given task may, or may not, run on a background thread.

If you always want to run tasks on a background thread, call the `ExecutorService` methods such as `submit`, `invoke`, `invokeAll`.

---

Kill your `mutex` and `synchronized`. Since each bot instance is updating its own member fields, and each bot instance is being run exactly once in its own thread, there is no conflict across threads.

---

Your `BotRunner` class seems utterly redundant. The `Bot` class already has a `run` method. So `Bot` can be declared as implementing `Runnable` and serve as our task.

Your response data member field could just as well be a local variable.

```java
public class Bot implements Runnable
{
    private Statistic statistic = null ;

    void run() 
    {
        String responseData = firstHttpCall … 
        this.statistic = secondHttpCall ( responseData ) ;
    }
}
```

Simply submit your list of `Bot` objects to an executor service.

If your tasks involve blocking, such as making network calls, then you likely should be using [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) in Java 21+ for maximum performance.

In modern Java, an executor service is `AutoCloseable`. So we can use try-with-resources syntax to automatically close it.

```
try 
(
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() ;
)
{
     bots.forEach( executorService :: submit ) ;
}
System.out.println( "Tasks done. Executor service closed." ) ;
```

---

By the way… Never call `LocalDateTime.now`. That class cannot represent a moment as it lacks the context of a time zone or offset from UTC. To track a point on the timeline, use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: You're right, I didn't describe the problem quite correctly. @Basil Bourque, i meant that the list of bots itself will be executed until the execution time ends. (And for that reason i`ve added synchonized block in Bot#run. I expected the behavior that while the bot is already busy with another thread, we will hang on the monitor, waiting until another thread makes changes to the bot itself.

Comment: Okay @Basil Bourque, unfortunately, solution (swap execute -> submit) doesn't work, race-condition still present. Could you say what it causes? (Maybe edited question will simplify understanding my problem)

Comment: Since the nested loops will send the same `Bot` instances to the executor service, it’s not correct to say that “each bot instance is being run exactly once in its own thread”. But the question’s sketch contains no effort to actually query or use the result, so no-one can say  for sure whether there’s a race at that point (though it very likely is). Of course, replacing `execute` with `submit` does not change anything. It does not even attempt to address the question’s actual problem. Same for virtual threads. Why discuss performance, when the question is about *thread safety*?

Comment: Agree with you, @Holger. "each bot instance is being run exactly once in its own thread" not exactly describes my issue. I mean, each Bot should be thread-safety on nested loop iterations. Thats why i've tried use synchronized block on Bot#run method. (Any lock not works too)