# Race condition in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, synchronized

## What code must to do:

- execute `Bot#run` synchronous.

## What need to fix:

- sharing resource (`Bot.responseData or.. more`) between other bots and threads.

### Bot.run() execution stages:

1. http request -> get random value from server (like f8c3de3d-1fea-4d7c-a8b0-29f63c4c3454). **(server return always random value!)**
2. save value to `Bot.responseData`.
3. http request (use `Bot.responseData` as param) -> return JSON.
4. save JSON to `Bot.statistics`.
5. cleanup `Bot.responseData = null`.

**Bot entity:**

```java
public class Bot 
{
    private final BotStatistic statisic = new BotStatistic();
    private final Object mutex = new Object();
    private String responseData;    

    void run() 
    {
        synchronized(mutex) 
        {
          String myHost = "http://myhost";
          firstCall(myHost)
          secondCall(myHost);
          cleanup();
        }
    }

    private void firstCall(String host) 
    {
        // first http call -> responseData = "f8c3de3d-1fea-4d7c-a8b0-29f63c4c3454";
    }

    private void secondCall(String host) 
    {
        // second http call(responseData) -> 
        // JSON {"success": true, "requestValue": "f8c3de3d-1fea-4d7c-a8b0-29f63c4c3454"}
        statistic.add(json);
    }

    private void cleanup() 
    {
        this.responseData=null;
    }
}
```

**BotRunner entity:**

```java
public class BotRunner implements Runnable 
{
    private final Bot bot;
    
    public BotRunner(Bot bot) 
    {
        this.bot = bot;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
       bot.run();
    }
}
```

**Trying to execute in this way:**

```java
//init executor
LocalDateTime termination = LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(5L);
while (LocalDateTime.now().isBefore(termination)) 
{
    for (Bot bot : bots) 
    {
        executor.execute(new BotRunner(bot));
    }
}
//shutdown & close executor
```

### What i see now

After execution i see **1-2%** of duplicate `Bot.responseData` from DIFFERENT `Bot`. Stuff like that:

```
thread-1 : start (Bot@44g35)
thread-1 : f8c3de3d-1fea-4d7c-a8b0-29f63c4c3454
thread-2 : start (Bot@898g)
thread-2 : f8c3de3d-1fea-4d7c-a8b0-29f63c4c3454
thread-1 : end
thread-2 : end
```

### What i must to see

```
thread-1 : start (Bot@44g35)
thread-1 : f8c3de3d-1fea-4d7c-a8b0-29f63c4c3454
thread-2 : start (Bot@898g)
thread-2 : 018b2f19-e79e-7d6a-a56d-29feb6211b04
thread-1 : end
thread-2 : end
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me :)

Comment: Your code performs no output, so how are you seeing anything?

Comment: How is this question any different from [the one you asked three days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78173650/801894)? And, what happened when you tried Basil Borque's suggestions? It looks as if you rejected those.

Comment: Make sure your http client isn't caching responses if identical url. You haven't shown http client, how response is parsed or what the output is based on, all of which would help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete, so I cannot be sure - but you must be sharing a variable between threads.

The `Bot` class is **not threadsafe** based on the code fragment you give (`responseData` is shared).  I am curious why you'd even attempt to solve thread safety issues with a 20-year approach like `synchronized(mutex)`; this would just not be necessary if the your Bot threads were certainly not shared.  (A more modern approach would to use a [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)).

How are you creating the collection of Bots? Are these all distinct instances?

Or how are you making the HTTP calls - is that code thread-safe?

And as @tgdavies says, how are you making any output?

Comment: Okay, @AndrewL. Create bots using for cycle, on each iteration do list.add(new Bot) and store it in List<Bot>. Http calls from apache.http.

Comment: If something is “a 20-year (old) approach”, then it’s `Lock`. The `synchronized` statement is even older, however, that does not mean that it is inappropriate. Being “more modern” does not solve any problem.